# Rebus 5.3.1 : Response sent in chunks are all received at once after sending handler completes execution

Tags: rebus

With Rebus version 1 we used to send the response for SearchTaskRequest in chunks of 20 to the client. 
After upgrading it to Rebus 5.3.1 all the chunks are sent after execution of Handler(SearchTaskRequest) completes.

Please check the code below.

```
public async Task Handle(SearchTaskRequest message)
{
        // business logic to get tasks

    var taskDtoLsts = taskList.Split(20);
    foreach (var taskDtoLst in taskDtoLsts)
    {
        var response = new SearchTaskResponse
        {
            TaskDtoList = taskDtoList,
            UserId = message.UserId,
            UniqueId = message.UniqueId
        };
        _bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(TaskQueue, response).Wait();
    }
}
```

What we expect is, Client should receive response in chunk of 20 instead of getting all the tasks at the end.

Comment: Did you do any debugging.  Where is the code delaying?  Are you getting to the handle only at the end?   Is code stopping at the Wait()?  You may not be getting the "end of the wait" after each response.  You may only be getting one "end of wait" when all 20 responses are sent.

Comment: public async Task Handle(SearchTaskResponse message) { ... } is called only once all the chunks are sent from Handle(SearchTaskRequest message) { ... } In the early version the SearchTaskResponse was immediately called as soon as the 1st chunk was sent

Comment: Are you trying to merge 20 responses into one?  Or just process the response 20 at a time?  the response may be so quick that it looks like you are getting all at the end when you are actually getting in groups of 20.  I'm not sure why you need the Wait() in the send.  The send is blocking and doesn't need an additional block using the wait.

Answer (score 2):

Rebus enlists all of your bus operations in the same "transaction context" (which is what Rebus' handler transaction is called), ensuring that messages get sent when your handler has finished executing.

The reason is that code like this is very common:

```cs
public async Task Handle(DoStuffCommand message)
{
    var someEntity = someRepository.Load(message.EntityId);

    someEntity.DoStuff();

    await bus.Publish(new DidStuffEvent(someEntity.EntityId));
}
```

As you can see, it loads an entity via an injected repository, and then it mutates the entity. After that it publishes an event, notifying the world about what it did.

The thing is this: When you configure a unit of work to commit your database transaction after the successful execution of handlers, it's paramount that published events do NOT get published before that unit of work has committed.

E.g. in cases where there's a key violation, a database deadlock, etc. you will not know until you try to commit the database transaction.

If Rebus had already published outgoing events at that time, then you would have a problem.

Therefore, Rebus will by default enlist all of your sent/published messages in the transaction context and not try to send/publish until after your unit of work has been successfully committed.

So... what can you do?

You can simply dismantle Rebus' transaction context each time you want to send an outgoing message!

EDIT: Since Rebus 6.0.0 it has been possible to do it like this:

```cs
using (new RebusTransactionScopeSuppressor())
{
    // (...) bus operations happen immediately in here
}
```

TL;DR: If you're on Rebus 6 or later, use `RebusTransactionScopeSuppressor` like shown above.

---

Here's the longer explanation, explaining what the suppressor does under the covers, which is relevant if you are using Rebus versions below 6:

The current transaction context can be found via the `AmbientTransactionContext.Current` property, and it can be set with `AmbientTransactionContext.SetCurrent(..)`.

You should wrap it up in an `IDisposable` like this:

```cs
public class RebusTransactionContextSuppressor : IDisposable
{
    readonly ITransactionContext transactionContext = AmbientTransactionContext.Current;

    public RebusTransactionContextSuppressor()
    {
        AmbientTransactionContext.SetCurrent(null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AmbientTransactionContext.SetCurrent(transactionContext);    
    }
}
```

which you can then use like this:

```cs
public async Task Handle(SearchTaskRequest message)
{
    // business logic to get tasks

    var taskDtoLsts = taskList.Split(20);
    
    foreach (var taskDtoLst in taskDtoLsts)
    {
        var response = new SearchTaskResponse
        {
            TaskDtoList = taskDtoList,
            UserId = message.UserId,
            UniqueId = message.UniqueId
        };
        
        using (new RebusTransactionContextSuppressor()) 
        {
            await _bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(TaskQueue, response);
        }
    }
}
```

---

PS: I changed `_bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(TaskQueue, response).Wait()` into `await _bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(TaskQueue, response)`, because you should always `await` `Task`s when you can.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. In this response handler we call SignalR to send the response at client. After implementing the way you suggested, following does not send it to client.  await GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<THub>().Clients.Group(Rebus.Pipeline.MessageContext.Current.Headers[Headers.CorrelationId]).searchResultFound(message.TaskDtoList, message.MessageId);

Comment: Once we set AmbientTransactionContext.SetCurrent(null); that response received by Handler which tries to fetch SignalR client group by CorrelationId can not forward this response further. So this solution is not working so far. Request your attention @mookid8000 . Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks for RebusTransactionContextSuppressor @mookid8000, very helpful - was running out of memory sending 3 million messages :-)

Comment: whoa that's a lot of messages 